# Textbooks to read after Armstrong Topology

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

I just finished reading through Armstrong - Topology and I'm looking for a logical next step to keep going in learning more topology.  I've taken courses in Real + Complex Analysis, Algebra, Geometry and others and am a third-year undergrad for reference.  I'm considering Hatcher - Algebraic Topology or Bredon - Topology and Geometry for two slightly different treatments, but I'm not sure if there are better roads to take.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Those are good books. After learning about a given topic, you might want to occasionally glance at Peter May's (usually highly elliptical) treatment in *A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology* to get a more abstract POV.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Michael Müger' ''Topology for Working Mathematician''
it is detailed and consist everything.

Comment: @RDK The question is asking for book recommendations, so this answer seems fine to me (unless you don't think this book is appropriate?).

Comment: Oh, I didn't check the question. My miss, sorry for that :(